# Notification not showing when app is in foreground in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I am using Firebase push notification in kotlin and below are the code snippet for showing push notification

```
 mNotifyManager = getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
        createChannel(mNotifyManager)
    val mBuilder = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "bks-channel")
            .setLargeIcon(largeIcon)
            .setContentTitle("Bks")
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.app_icon)
            .setContentText(message)
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
    mNotifyManager.notify(getRandomNumber(), mBuilder.build())
```

And the createChannel() function is :

```
    @TargetApi(26)
private fun createChannel(notificationManager: NotificationManager)
{
    val name = "bks"
    val description = "bks"
    val importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT

    val mChannel = NotificationChannel(name, name, importance)
    mChannel.description = description
    mChannel.enableLights(true)
    mChannel.lightColor = Color.BLUE
    notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel)
}
```

Below are the server logs:

```
 array(1) {
  [9]=>
  array(2) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(14) "ABL Staff USER"
    ["fcm_response"]=>
    array(2) {
      ["fields"]=>
      array(3) {
        ["data"]=>
        array(4) {
          ["click_action"]=>
          int(2)
          ["title"]=>
          string(19) "Attendance Reminder"
          ["body"]=>
          string(49) "Hi ABL Staff USER, Please mark your attendance ! "
          ["sound"]=>
          string(7) "default"
        }
        ["registration_ids"]=>
        array(11) {
          [0]=>
          string(152) "device_token_1"
        }
        ["notification"]=>
        array(4) {
          ["click_action"]=>
          int(2)
          ["title"]=>
          string(19) "Attendance Reminder"
          ["body"]=>
          string(49) "Hi ABL Staff USER, Please mark your attendance ! "
          ["sound"]=>
          string(7) "default"
        }
      }
```

Same are working for below android o in foreground and background but not in android o or above

Answer (score 0):

FCM has sent two type of notification

1. Notification Message
2. Data Message

Send the **data message** to show a notification when the app in the background

For more details check the below link

[Firebase data message](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#data_messages)

Comment: Is there a way to build push notifications withou firebase? example: android app with php backend-server, send notification to app from server.

Answer (score 0):

Are you creating channel by name   "bks-channel" ? Looks like you are not creating bks-channel instead you are creating channel by name bks.

Update your create channel method.

```
 @TargetApi(26)
  private fun createChannel(notificationManager: NotificationManager)  {
    val name = "bks-channel"
    val description = "bks"
    val importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT
    val mChannel = NotificationChannel(name, name, importance)
    mChannel.description = description
    mChannel.enableLights(true)
    mChannel.lightColor = Color.BLUE
    notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel)
  }
```

Comment: channel ID has to be same but name can be anything.I mean what you pass to notification builder and the created channel ID has to be same.